# How do I build docker images without docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Is there some lightweight way I can build a docker image within a container without having a working docker machine. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$ docker run -it --rm docker:latest

/ # mkdir test
/ # touch test/Dockerfile
/ # docker build test
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Assuming I had a valid Dockerfile in place, is there some way I could create an docker image from within a container like this?

Comment: you should read the doc on that subject https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem could be that you're missing the `--privileged` flag, but in general, your questions can probably be answered here: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

And you might take the time to read the blog linked there detailing some of the pitfalls of using docker-in-docker.